# CIK Webscraping from EDGAR - R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to build a cik lookup function for the project I am working on. I found the following [answer](https://gist.github.com/ddd1600/3934032):

```
require(XML)
require(RCurl)

getCIK = function(ticker) {
  stopifnot(is.character(ticker))
  uri = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar"
  response = getForm(uri,CIK=ticker,action="getcompany")
  html = htmlParse(response)
  CIKNode = getNodeSet(html, "//acronym[@title=\"Central Index Key\"][text() = \"CIK\"]")
  CIKNodeText = sapply(CIKNode, function(x) xmlValue(getSibling(getSibling(x))))
  CIK = sub(" .*","",CIKNodeText)
  CIK = sub("^0*","",CIK)
  CIK
}

getCIK("GE")
# "40545"
```

but when I type `getCIK("CLDR")`. I am getting

> character(0)

I wanted to build my own function:

```
library(rvest)
ticker = "cldr"
#loc = "New York"
session <- html_session("https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/cik.htm")
form <- html_form(session)[[1]]
filled_form <- set_values(form, query = name)

query <- rvest:::submit_request(session, filled_form)
```

I got

> Error: Could not find possible submission target.

I tried entering versions of "submit", but I didnt have any luck. Could someone suggest me some guidance?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

"CLDR" simply did not work because the ticker for Cloudera is somehow not updated in the EDGAR system. The `getCIK()` from the first code snippet works well when other tickers are provided.

You can quickly change the lookup from ticker-based to company_name based as below -

```
require(XML)
require(RCurl)

getCIKFromCompanyName = function(company_name) {
  stopifnot(is.character(company_name))
  uri = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar"
  response = getForm(uri,company=company_name,action="getcompany")
    html = htmlParse(response)
  CIKNode = getNodeSet(html, "//acronym[@title=\"Central Index Key\"][text() = \"CIK\"]")
  CIKNodeText = sapply(CIKNode, function(x) xmlValue(getSibling(getSibling(x))))
  CIK = sub(" .*","",CIKNodeText)
  CIK = sub("^0*","",CIK)
  CIK
}

getCIKFromCompanyName("Cloudera")
```

Now, this works well when there is exactly one company name similar to the parameter that you provide. This fails in case of "Google" because there are multiple company names with "Google" present in it.

You'll have to resort to some logic where you first search using ticker and only if that doesn't work, use the company names.

There are further problems with getting the Company Names right. For eg., if you search for "Tesla Inc.", the fetch fails. You have to search for "Tesla Motors" as that is the original name of the company.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for replying. Yes there are challenges with supplying company names, thats why I want to do with ticker. 

This is why I want to build R to goto https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/cik.htm and submit the symbol. Which will return the CIK. Could you provide some suggestion on how to do it?